# Screen Scraping using JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to get data from this web site with web scraping. http://myservices.ect.nl/tracing/objectstatus/Pages/Overview.aspx:

[image]

I used JSoup before  for more static HTML sites, but this one is more difficult because before I get the HTML table on the site have to click one button and I don't know if it's possible to use JSoup to manipulate the button.

After click this button I get a HTML table, I want to get data only where modality is Barge.

Thank you for your tip to use Firefox, now I have the table with some another page information. Can you tell me how can i get only table information? Output that I get is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `Selenium` HTML Unit Driver for that.

[Selenium Info](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

[Maven/Download Binary JAR](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.37.1)

[HTML Unit Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver)

Here is full working `example`. It will visit the `website` ,`click` the button and then you can get the `data` from the page.

**Edit: Only get the table value**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class GetData {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://myservices.ect.nl/tracing/objectstatus/Pages/Overview.aspx");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // select barge
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl15_g_ce17bd4b_3803_47f6_822a_2b8dd10fc67d_ctl00_dlModality"))).selectByVisibleText("Barge");
        // click button
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("button80")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //get only table text
        WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.className("grid-view"));
        String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
        // do whatever you want now, These are raw table values.
        System.out.println(htmlTableText);

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and your response, i really grateful, but i am not getting the table with this code, i get page source without the table, because i want want to get is only html table with only where the modify Barge, Thank you.

Comment: Try with FirefoxDriver instead of HtmlUnitDriver and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you now i have html table using with FirefoxDriver, But can you please tell me how i can get only table not all page source, i put one image to show what i mean, i will be very happy if you can how me some way. Thank you

Comment: Dear Makky can you help me with some issue please, above code give me table "grid view" as a string is that possible to get the table html format or something like <table><tbody><tr> or is that possible to mix Selenuim with soup something like Element table1 = doc.select("grid-view").first();  thanks a lot ?

Answer (score 2):

Every "click" (or any interaction of that sort) is a request to the server and a response to the browser. So, a possible solution is not to use JSoup for the initial page, but for the result page. For instance, open a POST to the page that returns the table, passing the parameter responsible for returning the modality `Barge`. You can use a tool like Firebug (for Firefox) or Chrome Developer Tools to check what's the conversation (request/response), so that you can emulate that with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe browser emulator for java will be useful for your problem - please consider this one - HtmlUnit.

> It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke
>   pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your
>   "normal" browser.

[HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)